# python - from txt file to dictionary and to json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to convert a file to json. 
The file has the format:

```
Temp=24.0* Humidity=41.0% Date=02/01/17-20:37
Temp=24.0* Humidity=42.0% Date=02/01/17-20:38
Temp=24.0* Humidity=42.0% Date=02/01/17-20:39
```

I'm using the following code:

```
list = {}
with open("record.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    if not ("Failed" in line):
      lists = line.split(" ")
      for l in lists:
        ll = dict([l.split("=")])
        // print(json.dumps(ll))
        list.update(ll)
```

And when I print the dictionary created i get.

```
>>> print (list)
{'Temp': '29.0*', 'Humidity': '31.0%', 'Date': '15/07/17-10:56\n', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Temp': '21.0*'}
```

I don't understand why. Does anyone knows why i don't get the entire dictionary?

Before converting to json i will also separate to sub-dictionary's by new line `/n`. Is this possible?

Comment: you are overriding the values in each iteration..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file contains the same set of unique keys three times so a corresponding representation in Python, which can then be serialised to JSON, is an array of dictionaries.

Try this change to your code:

`list = []
with open("record.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    if not ("Failed" in line):
      lists = line.rstrip().split(" ")
      ll = {}
      for l in lists:
        k,v = l.split("=")
        ll[k] = v
      list.append(ll)`

If you then do:

`print list`

You should get:

`print list
[{'Date': '02/01/17-20:37', 'Temp': '24.0*', 'Humidity': '41.0%'}, {'Date': '02/01/17-20:38', 'Temp': '24.0*', 'Humidity': '42.0%'}, {'Date': '02/01/17-20:39', 'Temp': '24.0*', 'Humidity': '42.0%'}]`

You can then dump to JSON with:

`import json
json.dumps(list)
'[{"Date": "02/01/17-20:37", "Temp": "24.0*", "Humidity": "41.0%"}, {"Date": "02/01/17-20:38", "Temp": "24.0*", "Humidity": "42.0%"}, {"Date": "02/01/17-20:39", "Temp": "24.0*", "Humidity": "42.0%"}]'`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of dictionaries like this and then can do whatever modification you want to do.

```
list = {}
complete_list=[]
with open("record.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    if not ("Failed" in line):
      lists = line.split(" ")
      lists[-1] = lists[-1].strip()       #it should remove the \n at the end.
      for l in lists:
        ll = dict([l.split("=")])
        // print(json.dumps(ll))
        list.update(ll)
        complete_list.append(list)
```